# how to remove line break in php when data is blank

Tags: php, line

I am trying to figure out how to remove blank line breaks, and have searched this forum for answer. There are lots of them, but I'm not clear on where I need to put the code. This is my scenerio:

This is what comes up as results from search when the 'Address2' line is empty of data:

**Office:** 
Boston
123 Stedman Street

Lowell, MA 01851
**Phone Number:** 
 
555-453-1234
**fax Number:** 
555-453-1236

This is the way it should be when 'Address2' is empty:

**Office:** 
Boston
123 Stedman Street
Lowell, MA 01851
**Phone Number:** 
 
555-453-1234
**fax Number:** 
555-453-1236

How do I remove the line break and where does the code go?

Here is my code:

```
echo '<span class="productdescription"><p>Office:   </p></span></h2>';
echo $query_row['Office'].'<br>';
echo $query_row['Address1'].'<br>';
echo $query_row['Address2'].'<br>';
echo $query_row['City'].', ';
echo $query_row['State'].'  ';
echo $query_row['Zip'].'<br>';
echo '<p><strong>Phone Number: </strong></p>';
echo $query_row['Phone'].'<br>';
echo '<p><strong>Fax Number: </strong></p>';
echo $query_row['Fax'].'<br><br>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check if there's any data before you echo it out:

```
echo $query_row['Address1'].'<br>';
if(!empty($query_row['Address2'])) // This will skip if the field if it's empty
    echo $query_row['Address2'].'<br>';
echo $query_row['City'].', ';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it, you want everything in one line if there's only one address line, but a sepparate address block if there are two address lines.

What about this:

```
echo '<span class="productdescription"><p>Office:   </p></span></h2>';
echo $query_row['Office'].'<br>';
echo $query_row['Address1'];
if($query_row['Address2'] != "") echo '<br>'.$query_row['Address2'].'<br>';
echo $query_row['City'].', ';
echo $query_row['State'].'  ';
echo $query_row['Zip'].'<br>';
echo '<p><strong>Phone Number: </strong></p>';
echo $query_row['Phone'].'<br>';
echo '<p><strong>Fax Number: </strong></p>';
echo $query_row['Fax'].'<br><br>';
```

Comment: this worked, except for when there is data for 'address2' it then creates a line break. Thanks for your help, great stuff